# Netbeans breakpoints not working with xdebug

Tags: php, netbeans, windows-xp, xdebug, easyphp

Right i'm pulling my hair out on this one.

I'm using Netbeans, EasyPHP, and Installed xdebug using by copy/pasting my phpinfo() results into the xdebug wizard which then tells you which .dll file you need to download.

Well i've followed all the instructions, my phpinfo() now says xdebug is installed, I've added the appropiate lines in my php.ini file. However, my breakpoints in Netbeans do not work! I know that xdebug is installed because if I manually add `xdebug_break()` to my code then they act as a breakpoint.

How can I get netbeans and breakpoints to work without manually using the xdebug php function everytime ?!

PS. I know this question has been asked a million times but I've followed the other solutions and none have fixed my problem!

I'm using XP if that shines any light on the matter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many painful hours, I have found out that I had both:

```
extension = php_xdebug.dll
```

uncommented in my `php.ini` file and:

`zend_extension = C:\path-to-xdebug-file\php_xdebug.dll`

added in my `php.ini` file. You're supposed to have one or the other!

Anyway I changed

`extension = php_xdebug.dll`

to

`;extension = php_xdebug.dll`